# Gap Statistic Method

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, k-means

```
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.io as sio
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    from sklearn.svm import SVC

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    datafile = sio.loadmat(filename)
    data = datafile['bow']
    sizedata=[len(data), len(data[0])]
    gap=[]
    SD=[]    
    for knum in xrange(10,20):
            print knum
            #Clustering original Data
            kmeanspp = KMeans(n_clusters=knum,init = 'k-means++',max_iter = 100,n_jobs = 1)
            kmeanspp.fit(data)
            dispersion = kmeanspp.inertia_
            #Clustering Reference Data
            nrefs = 10
            refDisp = np.zeros(nrefs)
            for nref in xrange(nrefs):
                refdata = np.random.random_sample((sizedata[0],sizedata[1]))
                refkmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=knum,init='k-means++',max_iter=100,n_jobs=1)
                refkmeans.fit(refdata)
                refdisp = refkmeans.inertia_
                refDisp[nref]=np.log(refdisp)
            mean_log_refdisp = np.mean(refDisp)
            gap.append(mean_log_refdisp-np.log(dispersion))
            #Calculating standard deviaiton
            sd = (sum([(r-m)**2 for r,m in zip(refDisp,[mean_log_refdisp]*nrefs)])/nrefs)**0.5
            SD.append(sd)
    SD = [sd*((1+(1/nrefs))**0.5) for sd in SD]
    #determining optimal k
    opt_k = None
    diff = []
    for i in xrange(len(gap)-1):
        diff = (SD[i+1]-(gap[i+1]-gap[i]))
        if diff>0:
            opt_k = i+10
            break
    print diff
    plt.plot(np.linspace(10,19,10,True),gap)
    plt.show()
```

Here I am trying to implement the **Gap Statistic method** for determining the optimal number of clusters. But the problem is that every time I run the code I get a different value for k.
What is the solution to the problem?
How can the value of optimal k differ for the same data?

*I have stored the data in a `.mat` file beforehand and I am passing it as an argument via terminal*

I am looking for the smallest value of k for which `Gap(k)>= Gap(k+1)-s(k+1)` where `s(k+1) = sd(k+1)*square_root(1+(1/B))` where sd is the standard deviation of the reference distribution and B is the number of copies of Monte Carlo sample

Otherwise stated, I am searching for the value of k for which

`s(k+1)-Gap(k+1)+Gap(k)>=0`

Comment: Gap Statistic method does not determine the optimal number of clusters. This is statistics. The number is fixed, just unknown. What this method does it estimate that number.  
You can expect values to differ if the algorithm uses randomization. Try setting a seed (`np.random.seed`) at the beginning, and see if the values change between runs.  This is not to say you should always seed the same value, but to show where the randomness comes from.

Comment: seed for what? K means?

Comment: `np.random.random_sample`

Comment: Yes I used that for getting my refernce distribution

Comment: `refdata = np.random.random_sample((sizedata[0],sizedata[1]))`

I used this code

Comment: Yes, and suggested you try running the code with a constant seed

Comment: But in the paper **Estimating the number of clusters in a data set via the gap statistic** by **Robert Tibshirani**, it is mentioned that 


_In each case, we estimate E*n{log(Wk)} by an average of B copies log(Wk*), each of which is computed from a **Monte Carlo** sample X1*, X2*,....,Xn* drawn from our reference distribution_

Comment: Doesn't it mean that we have to take different random samples each time?

Comment: You will, but you can't expect the results to be exactly the same for each run, if the Monte Carlo samples are taken each time are not the same.  In order to reproduce the results, you need to random choices that were previously made, to be made again. If you provide the pseudo-random generator with the same initial seed, then the random sequence it will produce will also be the same (per run of the program).

Comment: I understand that the same sequence is obtained if seeded beforehand.

Won't it be the same thing if I take `refdata = np.random.random_sample((sizedata[0],sizedata[1]))` out of the `for` loop?

Or `np.random.seed(0)` does something different?

Comment: Well, if I use `np.random.seed()` to get same results then it eventually violates the algorithm behind the **Gap statistic** method where it has been mentioned that the samples are **Monte Carlo** samples drawn from the reference distribution

Comment: Furthermore, how do I know that the estimate I am getting is correct, if I get different estimates for different run of the program.

Comment: So I guess the right method to get the estimate, as they did in their paper will be to run 50 or more trials and take the number which comes the maximum number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems with your simulation:

```
1- sd = (sum([(r-m)**2 for r,m in zip(refDisp,[mean_log_refdisp]*nrefs)])/nrefs)**0.5
```

Why did you multiply the second component of zip by nrefs that is not needed according to the original paper.

2-

```
 if diff>0:
        opt_k = i+10
        break
```

if diff>0 you want diff>=0 since equality can happen a
About why you get different number of clusters each time, as people said it is monte carlo simulation so there can be randomness and also it depends on what you are clustering and your dataset. I suggest you to test your algorithms against Silhouette and Elbow to get a better idea about number of clusters.

Answer (score -2):

One option is to run your function several times and then average the gap statistics and the s values, and find the smallest k where the average s(k+1)-Gap(k+1)+Gap(k) is greater than

This will take longer but give a more reliable result.